# Why Vue Can't Find Variable When Render Computed Property In Setup Script To Template

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I am migrating to Vue SFC and have problem using computed property.

With the following code, I want to create two rows, and the visibility of the bottom row (the content row) can be toggled by clicking the top row (the title row).

```
<!-- components/Note.vue -->
<script setup>
import { marked } from "marked";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  id: Number,
  title: String,
  create: String,
  content: String
});

const showContent = ref(false);
const elContent = ref(null);

const scrollHeight = computed(() => {
  return elContent.value.scrollHeight + "px";
});

const markedContent = computed(() => {
  return marked.parse(content.value);
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="row" @click="showContent=!showContent">
    <div class="col-9">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="col-3">{{ create }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" :style="{height:showContent?scrollHeight:0}" ref="elContent">
    <div class="col">{{ markedContent }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the error message

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function (9)
"
"
" at <Note"
"id=27"
"title=\"1Lorem Ipsum\""
" ..."
">"
"
"
" at <App>"

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core (9)
"
"
" at <Note"
"id=27"
"title=\"1Lorem Ipsum\""
" ..."
">"
"
"
" at <App>"

Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: content
```

However, if I don't use computed property, but the `marked.parse` method directly in the template, then everything works smoothly.

```
<!-- This is fine -->
<div class="row" :style="{height:showContent?scrollHeight:0}" ref="elContent">
  <div class="col">{{ marked.parse(content) }}</div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can tell me why this happens and how should I use computed property in script setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `props.probName` pattern to access props in script-setup files. However, in the template section, you must use `probName` directly.

So in your case, use `props.content` instead of `content` to address the issue.

```js
const markedContent = computed(() => {
  return marked.parse(props.content);
//return marked.parse(props.content.value);
})
```

The `props` name comes from the definition of your props, where you choose a variable name to hold all properties.

```js
// Here you've defined a variable name (props) that represents all properties
const props = defineProps({
  id: Number,
  title: String,
  create: String,
  content: String
});
```

#### Access props directly in the setup

If you wish to access props directly (as in the template), you can destruct the `props` at the place:

```js
const {content, id, title, create} = defineProps({
  id: Number,
  title: String,
  create: String,
  content: String
});

const markedContent = computed(() => {
  return marked.parse(content);
})
```

#### UPDATE: A note from the comments

Keep in mind that destructing props is not straightforward. It brings more coding and complexity, therefore I avoid it.

> You need to always access props as props.x in order to retain reactivity. This means you cannot destructure defineProps because the resulting destructured variables are not reactive and will not update. ([link](https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/features/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure))

To tackle the losing reactivity problem, you need to either use `toRef` manually or leverage the [Vue Macros plugin](https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/features/reactivity-transform.html#reactivity-transform).

> [Reactivity Transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html) was an experimental feature, and has been deprecated

Comment: Please note that **you can't simply destructure props:** the object is reactive, and destructuring it breaks this reactivity; **the props will not update on changes.** You must either **(a)** create the props object and then (on a separate line) pass it through `toRefs()` and destructure that, which gives you normal refs; or **(b)** use the _experimental_ "reactive props destructuring" feature, which gives magically-reactive "normal" variables (a bit like a reactive object but plain values).